# Cobalt 360 video display is not correct

Tags: cobalt

After implement 360 video as howto_decode_to_texture.md described, we found that the display color is not correct after renderer thread.  could any one help to point out which caused it?

[input picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/343YH.jpg)

[Display picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8qdh.jpg)
[image: Create Context]

Comment: Hi there, I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking at in the input picture, it looks like the YouTube UI, but 360 video should only be applied to actual video.  Is that a video of the YouTube UI?  What is the value of SbDecodeTargetFormat that you are setting for your decoded frames, can you confirm that this matches up with their actual format?

Comment: Yes, the picture is YouTube UI, I put the UI as the video frame to check the graphic path. The picture format is NV12, and I set SbDecodeTargetInfo.format as kSbDecodeTargetFormat2PlaneYUVNV12. If I set it as kSbDecodeTargetFormat1PlaneRGBA and use another RGBA picture, the result is OK.

Comment: In https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/rc_11/src/cobalt/renderer/rasterizer/skia/hardware_resource_provider.cc#260, Cobalt need multi-plane for renderer NV12.  Add our create decode target code. we create one texture/imgrekhr for both Y plane and CbCr plane, and set plane info into imagekhr attributes, can cobalt support this?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response.  Yes, Cobalt supports multi-plane NV12, and in fact this is the only NV12 that it supports.  I notice in your code above that only plane 0 is setup, and it is copied to plane 1, so this is likely the issue.  Instead you should create a separate GL texture for the CbCr plane and assign it to planes[1].

Comment: Also note that Cobalt will access the plane textures in fragment shaders by using ".a" for the Y plane, and ".ba" for the CbCr plane.  Essentially, it assumes that the Y plane has format GL_ALPHA and that the CbCr plane has the format GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA.  This is configured here: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/rc_11/src/cobalt/renderer/rasterizer/egl/textured_mesh_renderer.cc#357

Comment: As an example, the linux-x64x11 port encodes the 3-plane YUV 420 (so it is not NV12, but it is similar in that it also uses multiple planes) output from FFmpeg into a decode target with 3 planes here: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/rc_11/src/starboard/linux/shared/decode_target_internal.cc

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation, as we must share the memory between HW decoder and GPU, so that we had to use it in this way. I will try to find if it's possible to separate Y plane and Cbcr Plane to different texture.  At the same time, does cobalt have plan to support NV12 in one plane?

Comment: Hi Kai, I'm not sure what you mean by "NV12 in one plane", by its very nature, NV12 has a separate Y plane and CbCr plane.  If these exist within one plane, what is the format of the GL texture produced (e.g. how would you access the Y component of pixel (x, y) and how would you access the UV component of pixel (x, y)?)  If there is some demand to support new texture formats, we certainly would like to know about it.

Comment: Also, I see you're using GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES.  On most platforms when the GL texture type is setup as GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, it implies that the GL driver will perform a YUV -> RGB conversion behind the scenes.  In this case, you would want Cobalt to treat the resulting texture as a normal RGBA texture.  Have you tried using kSbDecodeTargetFormat1PlaneRGBA with the NV12 image?

Comment: Hi, Andrew, with your suggestion and set the format as kSbDecodeTargetFormat1PlaneRGBA , the color display is OK. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  I'll add that as an official answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Summary of solution worked out in the comments)

When using GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES as the texture type, it often implies that the GL driver will perform a YUV -> RGB conversion behind the scenes.  Thus, in this case, you would want Cobalt to treat the resulting texture as an RGBA texture, and therefore you should use kSbDecodeTargetFormat1PlaneRGBA for the image.

The kSbDecodeTargetFormat2PlaneYUVNV12 format should be used when the output of your decoder is two separate textures (a texture for Y and a texture for UV), and in this case, Cobalt will use a fragment shader to perform the YUV -> RGB conversion.